# Load an entity from a URI

Tags: 8, entities, uri

I have a URI 'entity:node/27' and I want to load this entity, but I cannot find the correct helper function or class to use.

**I do not want to explode the string or regex the string**, I am fairly sure there is a function for this.

Comment: Yes this is for Drupal 8

Comment: perhaps the last 2 comments from https://www.drupal.org/node/2309797 is what you're looking for?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
$params = Url::fromUri("internal:" . $source_uri)->getRouteParameters();
$entity_type = key($params);
$entity = \Drupal::entityTypeManager()->getStorage($entity_type)->load($params[$entity_type]);
```